# Is there a way to increase the maximum amount of messages that can be contained in a SysV message queue?

Tags: c, ipc, message-queue, sysv, sysv-ipc

I just switched from POSIX to SysV because the limit is much higher on SysV (1024 vs 10). But I still need an higher limit. The limit should be changed at runtime, because it depends on the data the user chooses.

Using POSIX, it was possible to increase the limit but it was necessary to run the code as root every time and I cannot do that.

Is there a way to increase the limit in SysV?

Comment: Why do you need such a long message queue?  I can see 10 being a little short, but if 1024 is not enough then is there any limit that actually would suit?  If you accumulate that many messages at once then it sounds like the message consumer(s) are not keeping up with the message producer(s), and a longer queue isn't going to fix that.

Comment: Which System V implementation?  On Solaris, for example, there was a text file in `/etc` that could configure (override) values for Sytem V IPC limits at boot time.  But the details depend on the exact I/s.  The limits and the mechanism for changing them is not standardized.

Comment: `the limit is much higher` Is that the limit of queued messages? So buffer them in userspace instead. `1024 vs 10` Where does these numbers come from? Measurement? Source code? Documentation?

Comment: Using a queue for long-term storage seems "less than ideal". Another solution (e.g. a database) might be better suited.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that is the point. If too many messages are produced, the program keeps them in the message queue so the program can eventually read them and inform the user that those requests have not been successful.

Comment: @KamilCuk POSIX limit comes from the documentation, for Sys V I think it is machine/system dependent, for me is 1024 according to my measurement. I can't buffer them because I can only read those messages just before the program ends. Before that moment, the message queue is used by other processes.

Comment: Well then, @EnricoBersanoBegey, I think you have chosen the wrong tool for the job.  Message queues are an inter-process *communication* mechanism, not a data *storage* mechanism.  Inasmuch as messages are made of data, MQs do have a storage component, but they are not designed for or appropriate for the usage you describe.  Queue capacity provides for message producers to temporarily outpace message consumers, but in general and other than over short time spans, consumers need to keep up with producers.

Comment: There is a command for this : `ipcs`

Comment: @JohnBollinger Here's how the program works: differents processes have to comunicate through a message queue. Typically every message is read immediately and the mq is left empty. In other cases (if the user chooses unbalanced parameters), more messages are produced than are consumed and the message queue fills up quickly. Those data cannot be lost and cannot be buffered because other processes concur to take that data. I'm not trying to use a message queue as a data storage mechanism. This program terminates after a given amount of time (usually seconds or at most minutes)

Comment: --> And in the end, the unused messages should be buffered and displayed to the user

Comment: @EnricoBersanoBegey, if the program's design depends on being able to buffer an arbitrary number of messages in the queue then yes, it *is* using the queue as a storage mechanism.  If it is valid for the user to choose parameters that trigger this behavior then that constitutes a design flaw, and adjusting the queue limit is not a solution -- it only changes the likelihood of the program failing.  If such parameters are not valid then the program should fail gracefully when it is unable to enqueue a message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As SYSV IPC are considered deprecated, it is a pity to design brand new applications with thoses old fashioned services.

POSIX message queues are based on a file system. It is usually mounted on */dev/mqueue*:

```
$ ls -la /dev/mqueue
total 0
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   40 dec.  25 21:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4600 dec.  25 20:51 ..
```

A message queue is created with [mq_open()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_open.3.html). The *attr* parameter provides the ability to set some attributes:

```c
struct mq_attr {
  long mq_flags;       /* Flags (ignored for mq_open()) */
  long mq_maxmsg;      /* Max. # of messages on queue */
  long mq_msgsize;     /* Max. message size (bytes) */
  long mq_curmsgs;     /* # of messages currently in queue (ignored for mq_open()) */
};
```

According to the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html), the */proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max* file defines the ceiling value for the maximum number of messages in a queue. In Linux 5.4, its default value is **DFLT_MSGMAX** (10) and its upper limit is **HARD_MSGMAX** (65536).

The defaults values are defined in the Linux source code (cf. */include/linux/ipc_namespace.h*):

```c
#define DFLT_QUEUESMAX      256
#define MIN_MSGMAX          1
#define DFLT_MSG            10U
#define DFLT_MSGMAX         10
#define HARD_MSGMAX         65536
#define MIN_MSGSIZEMAX      128
#define DFLT_MSGSIZE        8192U
#define DFLT_MSGSIZEMAX     8192
#define HARD_MSGSIZEMAX     (16*1024*1024)
```

Here is an example program which creates a message queue. It receives as parameters the message queue name and the maximum number of messages in the queue:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  mqd_t mqdes;
  struct mq_attr attr;

  if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <mq-name> <msg_max>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  attr.mq_flags = 0;
  attr.mq_maxmsg = atoi(argv[2]);
  attr.mq_msgsize = 2048;
  attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

  mqdes = mq_open(argv[1], O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777, &attr);
  if (mqdes == (mqd_t) -1) {
    perror("mq_open");
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

At execution time we can verify that, by default, we can't go above 10 messages for the queue:

```
$ gcc mq.c -o mq -lrt
$ ./mq 
Usage: ./mq <mq-name> <msg_max>
$ ./mq /q0 5
$ ls -la /dev/mqueue/
total 0
drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root     60 dec.  25 21:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root   root   4600 dec.  25 20:51 ..
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xxxx   xxxx     80 dec.  25 21:09 q0
$ ./mq /q1 9
$ ./mq /q2 10
$ ./mq /q3 11
mq_open: Invalid argument
$ ls -la /dev/mqueue/
total 0
drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root    100 dec.  25 21:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root   root   4600 dec.  25 20:51 ..
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xxxx   xxxx     80 dec.  25 21:09 q0
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xxxx   xxxx     80 dec.  25 21:10 q1
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xxxx   xxxx     80 dec.  25 21:10 q2
```

Let's change the ceiling value from 10 to 256 for *msg_max*:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max
10
$ sudo sh -c "echo 256 > /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max"
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max
256
```

Now it is possible to create message queues with up to 256 messages:

```
$ ./mq /q3 11
$ ./mq /q4 256
$ ./mq /q5 257
mq_open: Invalid argument
$ ls -la /dev/mqueue/
total 0
drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root    140 dec.  25 21:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root   root   4600 dec.  25 20:51 ..
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xxxx   xxxx     80 dec.  25 21:09 q0
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xxxx   xxxx     80 dec.  25 21:10 q1
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xxxx   xxxx     80 dec.  25 21:10 q2
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xxxx   xxxx     80 dec.  25 21:15 q3
-rwxrwxr-x  1 xxxx   xxxx     80 dec.  25 21:16 q4
```

But as you say, increasing the ceiling value requires super user rights. It could be possible to create a "setuid helper" which increases the ceiling value. For example, the following program sets the ceiling value passed as parameter:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int fd;
int rc;
int msg_max;

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <msg_max>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  fd = open("/proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max", O_RDWR);
  if (fd < 0) {
    perror("open()");
    return 1;
  }

  rc = write(fd, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
  if (rc != strlen(argv[1])) {
    if (rc >= 0) {
      errno = EIO;
    }
    perror("write()");
    return 1;
  }

  close(fd);

  return 0;
}
```

We can build it, change its owner/group to root and add the setuid bit:

```
$ gcc mq_helper.c -o mq_helper
$ sudo chown root mq_helper
$ sudo chgrp root mq_helper
$ sudo chmod 4555 mq_helper
$ ls -l mq_helper
-r-sr-xr-x 1 root root 17016 dec.  25 21:45 mq_helper
```

Then, it is possible to run this program from a non super user account to change the ceiling value of *msg_max*:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max
256
$ ./mq_helper 98
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max
98
```

**Note**: some file systems are mounted with the `nosuid` option to prevent users from introducing privileged programs.

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped a lot. Unfortunately though, I can't use the "setuid helper"... it keeps saying `open(): Permission denied` even though I have set all the permissions

Comment: Have you set the setuid bit (4555) or may be you are in a container without write access to /proc/sys file system?

Comment: I did set the setuid bit and no errors came out.
`ls -l mq_helper` output:
`-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 16976 Dec 25 15:26 mq_helper`

Comment: But you don't have the setuid bit: "s" does not appear in your display

Comment: Right. For some reason I'm having trouble setting that bit, I also tried to run `sudo chmod u+s mq_helper`. I'll try to figure out how to fix that. Thanks a lot